# Retrieving latest records from database and display in body?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm making a database driven site. But before I buy a .com domain, I was aiming to make the site more dynamic & interactive. Somehow, I got stuck with mySQL and PHP. I'm new to mySQL, and have a limited knowledge with PHP. I was able to get the page generator code running, all that's left is the dynamic homepage code.

So here's the thing, I want to get the 5 latest records from my database and display them in my homepage's formatted DIV boxes. I have a sample code but the records are displayed in a looped array. How can I get those data and store them in a $variable so that I could echo it out in my DIV boxes.

**My Website:** [ASCAS.tk](http://ascas.tk/)

**HOW CAN I ASSIGN VARIABLES TO EACH DATA FROM THOSE 5 ROWS?
ex. ($id_1, $id_2, $id_3, $title_1, $title_2, $title_3...)**

---

I also have a PHP code that displays all the records in one table.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","u967445970_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**HOW CAN I ASSIGN VARIABLES TO EACH DATA FROM THOSE 5 ROWS?
ex. ($id_1, $id_2, $id_3, $title_1, $title_2, $title_3...)**

Comment: `ORDER BY` date or datetime column?

Comment: I only want to assign variables.

Comment: your title says **2 latest**, in the question **5 latest**

Comment: Use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) with `LIMIT 5` if you don't have a column for date/time.

Comment: Don't change your question through midstream (especially when answers have already been given). First you asked how to get the last 5 entries, now you're asking how to assign variables. Get on Google and start reading the many tutorials. I'm done here; good luck with that.

Comment: sorry, I just want to assign each data with a variable. I want to display them in DIV boxes, not in tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your result variable with this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main LIMIT 5");
```

And if you want to order your last record ordering by (assuming in this case, i want to order by date) , this is the code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main order by id DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Change the `id` with your primary key

Comment: This won't give **latest** five

Comment: check the update, and what the result of my code?

Comment: Again it won't produce latest five. Did you try what you propose?

Comment: Assuming OP has a `DATE` column to start with. What if there are 1000's of records with no dates in them already?

Comment: Check my update, what is your primary key???

Comment: No quotes around `id` in `order by 'id'` use backticks. It's a column and not a search for data within a row. I.e.: `WHERE id='$var'` @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra

Comment: so how can I assign variables to the 5 latest rows that I just pulled?

Comment: i give quotes just for giving him the sign, -_-

Comment: A "sign"? What are you talking about? @ArryanggaAlievPratamaputra You need to give actual and proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main order by created_date DESC LIMIT 2");
```

OR try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main order by id DESC LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: how can I assign variables to the 5 latest rows that I just pulled? 
ex. $id1, $id2, $id3, $title1, $title 2....

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","u967445970_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM main order by date desc limit 0, 5");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){ 
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```